# Exception handling library in pure C

Tags: c, exception

Is there some crossplatform c-library for exception handling (to implement try / catch in C)?

I'm also looking for documentation how it's realized in c++ (how the interrupts are masking or something like this)

Comment: @Tim Yes, C++ trows exceptions and C doesn't, therefore he looks for a library to implement the same in C. I don't see what's hard to understand here.

Comment: There was this article: http://www.on-time.com/ddj0011.htm and this http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html

Comment: @ChristianRau I re-read it a few more times and finally saw what you saw. Made some edits, sorry for the noise (but it was initially quite difficult to understand)

Comment: A Google search for "c exception handling library" seems to turn up some likely results.

Comment: thanks a lot. I've made small implementation of exception handling and now i'm understand how it mades.

Answer (score 9):

You can try [exceptions4c](http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c); it's an exception handling library in ANSI C that supports: `throw`, `try`, `catch`, `finally` and a few more goodies. For example, it supports the *Dispose pattern*, so you can automatically release resources. You can also handle *signals* (such as `SIGFPE` and `SIGSEGV`) as if they were exceptions.

It's implemented on top of `setjmp` and `longjmp` (standard C library), and it's free software, so you can read and modify the source code.

Oh, by the way, I'm the author :) Please take a look at it, and compare it against [other alternatives](http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/wiki/alternatives) to see which fits you most.

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish similar results to C++ exception handling is to use setjmp and longjmp.  See the Wikipedia page for a trivial example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h.   Check out the source for the Lua interpreter for a real-world example.

Note that this will NOT be a true implementation of try/catch in the sense that you can call your library from C++ and get real exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

[XXL](http://www.zork.org/xxl/xxl.html) is one such library.

Answer (score 1):

The [OSSP ex](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/ex/) library would seem to satisfy your requirements. It exploits context switching facilities, and is thread safe. Well written and documented, like all the OSSP components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#define TRY         char *__exc_message = NULL; do
#define THROW(exc)  { __exc_message = exc; break; }
#define CATCH(exc)  while(0); if(__exc_message != NULL) { exc = __exc_message;
#define FINALLY     }

void Test(int a, int b)
{
    char *exc = NULL;

    TRY
    {
        if(a < b) THROW("A < B!");
        if(a > b) THROW("A > B!");

        TRACE_INFO("Ok :-)");
    }  
    CATCH(exc)
    {
        TRACE_ERROR(exc);
    }
    FINALLY
    {
        TRACE_INFO("Finally...");
    }
}
```