# What can LLVM represent that C cannot?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

As far as I know, it is almost true that any code that can be represented in the LLVM intermediate language, can also be represented in C, with two important exceptions:

- Exceptions. (No pun intended.)
- Signed integer arithmetic with well-defined behavior on overflow.

Is there anything else that can be represented in LLVM but not in C?

Comment: Variable-names are "less restrictive" in LLVM, but that's a small detail... can you provide a bit more context as for why you are asking this question? I'm having a hard time figuring out where you are headed. Also, someone else thinks the question should be closed because it's too broad

Comment: Signed integer arithmetic can be represented in C, it's just a lot of extra work (probably using unsigned integers for actual operations, then converting the result to the right signed value)...

Comment: @hyde I'm sure rwallace is thinking of the case that signed overflow in C is undefined behavior where it can be well-defined in LLVM. Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: Given that we write programming languages with exceptions in C, C can most definitely represent exceptions.

Comment: @MortenJensen I'm writing a compiler that uses C as its target language. I want to check to make sure I'm not missing anything that is problematic to express in C. That would *in fact* be a broad question, so I rephrased it as a question that is *in fact* concrete and specific, though I understand that is little defense against the trolls these days .

Comment: @Schwern Well, I meant reasonably directly; are you thinking of longjmp?

Comment: @MortenJensen Well, it is getting into semantics, what does "can represent" mean etc. C does have data types which don't support overflow.

Comment: @rwallace You've hit why this question is too broad. What is "reasonably directly" and how high level are we going? We've been implementing exception handling in C for decades.

Comment: @rwallace Is standard C absolute requirement? Take a look for example here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html (and I think nearly all compilers have support for defined integer overflow, for example).

Comment: @Schwern Okay, this is interesting; can you point me to a compiler that implements exception handling in C, and in your opinion does it well enough to be considered a success?

Comment: @hyde Yes precisely :) I believe this question is exactly about language semantics and primitives, and not about which kind of programs can be written in either language, since both are turing complete so it's moot to discuss that part. If rwallace agrees, he could add that to the original question to avoid that misunderstanding. I made it myself at first.

Comment: @rwallace C++ :) (originally) and any number of interpreters. We're going to get into semantics about "compiler" and I agree with Morten. We need a better understanding of your idea of "reasonably directly". Is [using a C library ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661308/exception-handling-library-in-pure-c)? If not, is it standard libraries only? What about things like GMP? How much C code are you willing to generate per operation? FWIW I'd suggest targeting LLVM, that's what it's designed for.

Comment: @Schwern I believe C++ moved past cfront before acquiring exceptions, but the C exception library in the linked question is remarkably comprehensive, more so than I would've anticipated. Thanks!

Comment: You can do defined signed integer overflow in C by adding extra checks and manual code for wrap arounds. At a philosophical level both the languages are turing complete. So you can do same things in both the language. Maybe not as "reasonably directly" as you want. Even things that can be programmed using exceptions can be done using C by explicitly passing around the exception information as parameters to the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to exception handling, other *big features* are [garbage collection](https://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html) and out-of-the-box [coroutines](https://llvm.org/docs/Coroutines.html). Going to a lower level, there are [trampoline intrinsics](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#trampoline-intrinsics), [patch points for JITs](https://llvm.org/docs/StackMaps.html), and direct support for [Obj-C ARC Runtime intrinsics](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#objective-c-arc-runtime-intrinsics).

C is Turing complete, so all of these things can be introduced to C with libraries and so on, but I put them as they are part of the LLVM language.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata for example, including LLVM's branch-weight and debugloc metadata.

Except that they can if you're willing to be tortuous enough about the C you write. I think that's general: IF you're willing to write really tortuous, unidiomatic C, THEN you can write anything. So I vote to close this as unclear.

EDIT: Most things probably are expressible in C given enough discipline, verbosity and preprocessing directives, but I wonder about [aliasing](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Gohman-AliasAnalysis.pdf).